# can't correctly set left margin in book down: affects odd pages only

Tags: r, geometry, bookdown

I have to create a document with a wide left margin for marker's notes. I have been able to set a left margin with the following output yml:

```
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
geometry: [a4paper, left=40mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]
documentclass: book
```

but the the wide margin only appears on odd page numbers. I have also tried to do it through a header inclusion like this:

```
documentclass: book
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

with the following in my preamble.tex file:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=40mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm
 }
```

but this gives the same result.

I was able to do something about it with this line in my preamble.tex:

```
\hoffset = 30pt
```

This applies the offset to all pages but I can't control the widths as I need to.

Please help. Thanks.